# Querying a Many to Many relation Junction table

Tags: javascript, database, typescript, typeorm

I have a many to many relation between my products and categories entity like this:

```
@Entity('products')
export class productsEntity extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

//..other columns

    @ManyToMany( type => categoryEntity, category => category.products, {eager: true,})
    @JoinTable({name:"products_categories",
                joinColumn: {name: 'productId', referencedColumnName: 'id'},
                inverseJoinColumn: {name: 'categoryId', referencedColumnName:'id'}
              })
    categories: categoryEntity[];
}
```

Then i have a category entity:

```
@Entity('categories')
export class categoryEntity extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({nullable: false, default: 'all', unique: true})
    title: string;
    
    @ManyToMany(()=> productsEntity, product => product.categories)
    products: productsEntity[];
}
```

I am trying to save a new product if the category exists in category Entity. by this code:

```
 async addProduct(productDetails: productsEntity, username, categor: categoryEntity){
        const {title, description, price, units}  = productDetails;
        try{ 
            let newProduct = new productsEntity();
            newProduct.title = title;
            newProduct.description = description;
            newProduct.price = price;
            newProduct.units = units;
            newProduct.soldBy = username;
            newProduct.categories = newProduct?.categories ?? [];
            newProduct.categories.push(categor);
            categor.products= categor?.products?? [];
            categor.products.push(newProduct);
            await newProduct.save();
            await categor.save();
            
        }
        catch(err){
            this.logger.error(err.message);
            throw new HttpException('Failed adding Product.', HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        }
    }
```

Now everything seems to be fine except one problem:

```
 productId | categoryId
-----------+------------
         8 |          2
        24 |          1
```

This gets updated instead of making a new row for a new product if i add with an existing id. like this

```
 productId | categoryId
-----------+------------
         8 |          2
        25 |          1
```

What am i doing wrong?? I cant find any clue.

Comment: When you make a save it inserts if the row does not exist if it does exist it updates it. Try newProduct.insert()

Comment: Do you need to define the join table that specific? We have had a bug in typeorm with aliasing the forgein Id in an enitiy making all sorts of bugs. I it is not exactly the same but it is worth a shot

Comment: @Jboucly doesn't help.